# load Bitmap efficiently when dimension aren't known

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I read through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to load bitmaps efficiently, and I executed it perfectly for creating thumbnails. But what happens when the ImageView in which I want to load the bitmap instead of having hardcoded size (for thumbnails I used 75x75 dp) its width and height are wrap content?

For being more specific:
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) the documentation provides this function

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,int reqWidth,
int reqHeight)
```

and computes the inSampleSize for the required width and height. I though of getting the device's width and height and subtract the padding of the image view but this one seems to me a bit of a hack. Is there any other way?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Get the views width/height directly, rather than working it out from the devices width and height.

You can do this using `myImageView.getHeight()` and `myImageView.getWidth();`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

> [Width and Height]. These dimensions define the actual size of the view on screen, at
>   drawing time and after layout. These values may, but do not have to,
>   be different from the measured width and height. The width and height
>   can be obtained by calling getWidth() and getHeight().

Then using the actual height/width, you can get the bitmap efficiently for the exact resolution needed.

Comment: how will this work since my imageView will strech until the bitmap I'm loading will fit in?

Comment: @libathos Will stretch til your bitmap fits? Set it to `match_parent` And load the image based on the maximum space is capable of fitting in. Or specify your own desired width, and the imageview will take the same size.